# Validate same values based on array of object

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I validate that a user does not input the same value for two opposite rules. In this example, we can block users when the name is `Test` but are block users when the name is not `Test`. The goal is to show an error message telling users that `name_is` and `name_is_not` can not have the same value. How can I write a validation for this? I could use lodash

```
const rules = [
  {rule: "name_is", value: "Test"},
  {rule: "name_is_not", value: "Test"},
  {rule: "surname_is", value: "Foo"}
  {rule: "surname_is_not", value: "Bar"},
  {rule: "name_is", value: "Fux"}
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert them to a `Map`, iterate it, for each key check `key + _not`:

```js
const rules = [
  {rule: "name_is", value: "Test"},
  {rule: "name_is_not", value: "Test"},
  {rule: "surname_is", value: "Foo"},
  {rule: "surname_is_not", value: "Bar"}
]


let m = new Map(rules.map(x => [x.rule, x.value]))

for (let [rule, value] of m.entries())
    if (m.get(rule + '_not') === value)
        console.log(rule, '???')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is use `Array.reduce` and check each time if there is a key with `_not` present and what its value is. If there is you can keep track of it in the `summary` object in the accumulator:

```js
const rules = [ {rule: "name_is", value: "Test"}, {rule: "surname_is", value: "Foo"}, {rule: "surname_is_not", value: "Bar"}, {rule: "name_is_not", value: "Test"} ] 

const result = rules.reduce((r,{rule, value}) => {
  let key = rule.replace('_not', '')
  r[key] == value ? r.summary[rule] = `same as ${key}` : r[rule] = value
  return r
}, {summary: {}}).summary

console.log(result)  // "name_is_not": "same as name_is"
```